# how to create a member peer to peer donation platform like ponzi scheme

Tags: php, sql

I have made lot of research on how to create an online platform where one user will be match to another user to make donation and receive incentive for the donation made after some days, i want to know if there is a plugin or software that can give me this result.

Comment: Aside from the fact that ponzi schemes are unethical, this is too broad. Flagged for intervention.

Comment: I want to make this for my client who want to go into this, i am less concern if its ethical or not, all i want is how do i go about it? what platform is the best to start with